# Freeze specific cells in an Excel worksheet

Tags: excel, freeze, worksheet

I have been working on an Excel workbook containing the separate worksheets for different products and in each worksheet there is two parts -
(i) Left most Column having the list of all limited no. of products with the Hyperlink to particular sheet for the Product Details   and
(ii) Right side part which is having a Table showing the details of product in particular worksheet.

Now coming to what *I actually need*...
***I want to freeze row containing Table Headers in such a way that when I scroll down, the left column containing the Product List should not be scrolled simultaneously.***

When I freeze panes selecting the cell which is bellow the Headers of table and at right side of the first column, Product List is also scrolled out...so that doesn't works for what I want.

I have attached an *Illustrative file* same as one on which I have been working.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ZdWTduwoBLRkVtNUluM01TX3c/view?usp=sharing

In that... I want to freeze the cells above **Row 8** and want to keep the **left column** as it is i.e. it should not be scrolled down.
*For example*, If I want to see the 29th Record of the Table...Then Headers of table should be visible and the complete list of product on the left side should be visible so that I can switch to any Product even if I am on 29th record.

This is it...Must see the attached file...and If you don't understand what i asked...reply me.

Comment: How about using `split` at B24?

Comment: But 16 records above that will also be stable...so that will not work...

Answer (score 0):

As split can not fulfill your request, i think you need using vba + freeze panes.
Below is what i did on the page.
1.Highlight D8 and click freeze panes 
2.Insert a button with the following macro code.

```
Sub BackToTop()
 Range("A8").Select
End Sub
```

[image]

So whenever I want back to the top, just click the button to show the list of All product